# How to align text left/center/right in the same line use \hfill?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I use the same latex for two piece of information, but the output alignment is a bit different:

Syntax:

```
\noindent \textbf{Udacity} \hfill Machine Learning Nanodegree \hfill Aug. 2014 -- Sept. 2015\linebreak

\noindent \textbf{Singapore Management University} \hfill M.S. in Data Management and Analytics \hfill Aug. 2014 -- Aug. 2015
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Each `\hfill` gets replace by the same amount to fill the available space horizontally. That's why your alignment seems odd. You can mark code using the "{}" buttom in the editor or by indenting it with 4 spaces. You should really post a complete compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228), beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`, including all that is necessary to produce your output/issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to accomplish the alignment isn't using `\hfill` but a `tabular` or `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
        @{}
        >{\bfseries}X
        >{\centering}X
        r
        @{}}
    ~\textsc{Education}\\
    \hline
    Udacity & Machine Learning Nanodegree & Aug. 2014 -- Sept. 2015\cr
    Singapore Management University & M.S. in Data Management and Analytics & Aug.
    2014 -- Aug. 2015\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but please make entries in the first column ragged right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you see the problem but if it is the end of the line:

`\linebreak` does something different to a paragraph break. Set `\parfillskip` to 0pt and use either `\par` or `\\` to separate both:

```
{%
 \parfillskip=0pt
 \noindent \textbf{Udacity} \hfill 
 Machine Learning Nanodegree \hfill 
 Aug. 2014 -- Sept. 2015
 \par %or \\ here    
 \noindent \textbf{Singapore Management University} \hfill 
  M.S. in Data Management and Analytics \hfill 
  Aug. 2014 -- Aug. 2015
 \par %important.
}
```